# Когда оправдано создание новых процессов в node.js

Tags: node.js

Я не могу понять когда оправдано создание нового процесса в node.js по средствам `cluster.fork();`.

Разве входящие запросы и без этого не будут порождать новые процессы?
Какой профит от программного создания нового процесса, пожалуйста приведите похожий на реальность пример.

Если знаете статьи на тему практического применения `fork` в node.js, я был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: Входящие запросы не создают новые процессы

Comment: Вы правы, нашел статью на эту тему. Я перехожу на node с php поэтому возникла путаница. PHP создает новые процессы на каждый новый запрос, которые после выполнения убиваются, я думал что node.js работает аналогичным образом, но нет... Nodejs постоянно держит в памяти запущенным один процесс, соответственно когда производительности одного ядра процессора не хватает можно сделать fork процесса. Надеюсь я правильно всё понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило, никогда оно вам не надо.

Node cluster можно использовать, когда вам нужно напрямую общаться между процессами. Но, в большинстве случаев, в этом нет необходимо и достаточно просто запустить несколько инстансов сервиса под каким-нить супервайзером по числу ядер, а потом балансить это дело чем-нибудь поверх. Тем же nginx'ом.

Если говорить о практических примерах, то к тому же экспрессу можно прикрутить кластер. В коде будет что-то типо:

```
// если это основной процесс
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const cpuCount = os.cpus().length;
    // создаём форки по числу ядер
    for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
// если это форк
else {
    const app = express();

    // обрабатываем запросы
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.json({status: "ok"});
    })

}
```

Comment: >>>" когда вам нужно напрямую общаться между процессами".
Можете привести реальный пример такой задачи, когда это требуется?

Comment: @abakan обновил ответ.